# Displayin tinyMCE after twice ajax call

Tags: ajax, tinymce

In my page, when a button is clicked, a div appears which has a textarea(tinyMCE). I have a close button for that div. When I open the div, do my job, close the div, and open the div again, tinyMCE editor doesn't appear.
Here is the summary of my problem
1-) Click button, onclick="doAjax()" and display the returned value in a DIV
2-) In that DIV, there is a textarea with tinyMCE. Everything is OK
3-) Close the div(in fact, just fadeOut() the DIV) Everything is OK
4-) Click the button on step 1 again, onclick="doAjax()" and display the returned value in a DIV
5-)In that DIV, THERE IS NOT A TEXTAREA WITH TINYMCE! 
I tried using some of them but couldn'T make it work

```
if (tinyMCE.get === 'undefined')
{
   tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'message');
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'message');
 }
```

This code shows tinyMCE only for the first time, not for the second or later. Any solutions?

-----------------------SOLUTION----------------------------------
Okey. I found a solution

```
var oldEditor = tinyMCE.get('message');
if (oldEditor != undefined) {
     tinymce.remove(oldEditor);
}
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'message');
```

That works fine!

Comment: The escaped single quote \' also appear in the original?

Comment: sorry. It was a PHP code, I removed other \'s but forget those two

Comment: If you found a solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: I can't. I editted my question by including the answer but I'm not allowed to post an answer for 8 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

I have posted your comment as an answer.

```
var oldEditor = tinyMCE.get('message');
if (oldEditor != undefined) {
    tinymce.remove(oldEditor);
}
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'message');
```

Always consider taking some time and posting the answer if you found it.

Thanks,
Sworoop

Answer (score 1):

came across the same problem and solved it by basically removing all of the instances before initializing it again

```
tinymce.remove();
tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
```