# TinyMce integration in ajax php page

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce

I create an html page having 1 buttons clicking on the first will call a php file "1.php" via ajax where there is a tinymce editor attached with a text area.When after opening the page i'm pressing the button the editor is appearing on the screen but problem arrives when i press the button for the second time the editor just vanished and a simple text area took it's place.Any idea why this error is occurring,

Also i tried to add a check portion before attaching the tiny editor for checking if there is already an editor attached then the older one will be removed and the newer one will took place.This code is running 100% successfully in google chrome but not in firefox / ie.This problem is just screwing me up,need ideas.

---

FOR CHECKING THE PREVIOUS INTEGRATION OF TINYMCE AND REMOVE THE FOLLOWING CODE IS WORKING FINE

```
 var oldEditor = tinyMCE.get('message');
    if (oldEditor != undefined) {
    tinymce.remove(oldEditor);
   }
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'message');
     //MESSAGE IS THE NAME OF TEXT AREA ON WHICH TINYMCE IS GOING TO BE INTEGRATED
```

Comment: Please any one...give me suggession

Comment: LEAVE IT...FOUND THE ANSWER IN ANOTHER POST

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434933/displayin-tinymce-after-twice-ajax-call?rq=1